# How set external gem into project using svn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svn, svn-externals, externals

I need to add gem into vendor folder as external using SVN.

Path to add gem  `/vendor/gem_name`.
Path to svn repo `path_to_svn_repos/gem_name/trunk`

I try to do it, but it remove all another externals and add my gem :(
I need to append this gem to existing externals list.

How can I do it?
Please, help

Comment: Rails version of your app.

Comment: how does rails version relates to svn configurations? o_O

Comment: Gem is file or directory? Stored in the same repo or in another?

Comment: gem is a directory with files, stored in another repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add external using RubyMine:

Right click in folder, then choose 'Subversion' and 'Edit properties',
and add gem with it's svn path.

[image]

And run `svn up` after this actions.

P.S. But I still don't know how can I do it using terminal.